# Validar formulario de Nome

Tags: html5, regex, validação

Estou com uma duvida com validação do html5, tenho pouco conhecimento com regex  preciso validar um formulário que obtenha apenas:

- Letras maiusculas e minusculas, com acentos e etc;
- Espaços em brancos;
- Não pode aceitar apenas espaços em branco;

Segue o código:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" minlength="4" pattern="[a-z\s]+$" required />
```

Estou usando este código mas o `pattern` não esta funcionando.

Comment: [Javascript + Unicode regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/280712/3937493)

Comment: Não sei qual o objetivo, mas será que não é mais "seguro" utilizar uma validação javascript como por exemplo https://jqueryvalidation.org ? Digo isso em relação a compatilidade cross browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código a seguir, vai permitir no mínimo 2 caracteres  e máximo 20 caracteres  e não permitir em branco:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" required>
```

Caso você não queira com número (apenas letras):

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-_\.]{1,20}$" required>
```

Permitir no mínimo 4 caracteres:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z-_\.]{3,20}$" required>
```

Veja algumas explicações:

- `^` - Afirma posição no início da seqüência de caracteres.
- `$` - Afirma posição no final da seqüência de caracteres, ou antes do terminador de linha direito no final da seqüência de caracteres (se houver).
- `-_` - corresponde a um único caractere na lista -_ (diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas).
- `{1,20}` - Quantificador - Corresponde entre 1 e 20 vezes, tantas vezes quanto possível, devolvendo conforme necessário.
- `a-z` - um caractere único no intervalo entre um (ASCII 97) e z (ASCII 122) (sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas).
- `A-Z` - um caractere único na faixa entre A (ASCII 65) e Z (ASCII 90) (sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Veja mais exemplos aqui: http://html5pattern.com/Names.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bLg24qog/5/

regex101 : https://regex101.com/r/iCXgjf/2

Comment: esta igual ¬¬ ...

Comment: agora sim champs

Comment: Adendo : `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`, e caso você use `-` no meio de `[]` o ideal é ele estar no final `[abc-]`, para não gerar problemas de sentença `0-9`, `0` até `9`. O `.` não necessita ser escapado entre de `[]`.

Comment: Fora estes pequenos detalhes esta indo bem :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" required name="full_name" pattern="^[^-\s][a-zA-ZÀ-ú ]*">
```

O required faz com que o campo seja obrigatório.
No regex eu não permito nada que comece com espaço.

Comment: mesmo assim ele aceita com apenas espaços em branco, ele valida e vai pro próximo input, obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Sim, verifiquei isso, fiz uma alteração acho que agora funciona ok. Fiz poucos testes, vê se está ok.

Comment: Adicione required ao campo. E no regex use

`pattern="^[^-\s][a-zA-ZÀ-ú ]*" `